# Can you tell which SelectField triggered an onChange?

Tags: material-ui

I am working on a component which may have any number of SelectFields and want to use one onChange handler for all of them. Can I tell which SelectField triggered the onChange?

At this point I resorted to

```
onChange={this.onSelectChange.bind(this, key)};
```

With *key* taking on a value that identifies the SelectField. The SelectField is generated in the body of an Array.map.

I wanted to avoid the bind, but haven't found a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to link the function, call it explicitly. And I'd rather use the id of an element for identification than the key:

```
id="coolSelect" onChange={(e)=>this.onSelectChange(e.target.id)}
```

Comment: Using e.target.id was one of my first attempts (sorry should have mentioned this in my question). The event parameter in the handler seems to be associated with the MenuItem, not the SelectField. And the MenuItem element is not related to the SelectField in the DOM.